# Add items to multiple rows Excel c#

Tags: c#, excel

I have a windows form application. In this application, I want to export some of my data in my form to excel. I have figured out how to create a Excel file and also stored some value to it. However one thing I am not sure is if there a way to add items to excel rows using a for loop (to figure out the rows and column according to how many data you have)? because it is pretty inefficient if you want to add a list of items let say 1000 items one by one.

For example: To add one item to specific cell one at a time, we can do something like this:

```
xlSomeDetail.Cells[1,1] = "Teacher Id";
xlSomeDetail.Cells[1,2] = "first name";
xlSomeDetail.Cells[1,3] = "Last Name";
xlSomeDetail.Cells[1,4] = "Email";
xlSomeDetail.Cells[1,5] = "Salary";
```

Now is there something like this if I want to do it without adding rows one by one?

```
//declare aRange variable
Excel.Range aRange;

 aRange = (Excel.Range)xlSomeDetail.get_Range("A1", "M1");

 //something like this? I am not sure 
for (int i = 1; i< aRange.Rows; i++{

      xlSomeDetail.Cell[1, i+ 1] = //somestring?
}
```

Are there any better method of doing this?

Comment: if you put all of your data into a 2 dimensional object array first (object [,] myData = new object[rows,cols]) with nested for loops - this can then be allocated directly to the Range (aRange.Value2 = myData;)

Comment: Thanks, i will give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

try to create multiple Xl  objects
befour this split your data as per  your requirment in to multiple datatables

```
         [DllImport("user32")]
           private static extern bool GetWindowThreadProcessId(int hWnd, out int id);


           for(i=0;i<2;i++)
                    {

                     oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                                    oXL.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1;
                                    oXL.Visible = false;

                                    //Get a new workbook.
                                    oWB = (Excel.Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing));
      oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oWB.Worksheets.get_Item(1);+
             oSheet.Name = "Summary Report";//Change the name as per your requirment
                             ExcelRowsCount = 2;
                      for (int RowsCount = 0; RowsCount < dt.Rows.Count; RowsCount++)
                                {
                     for (int ColumnsCount = 0; ColumnsCount < dt.Columns.Count; ColumnsCount++)
                                    {
                                        if (RowsCount.Equals(0) && ColumnsCount.Equals(0))
                                            oSheet.Cells[2, 1] = dt.Rows[RowsCount][ColumnsCount].ToString();
                                        else
                                            oSheet.Cells[ExcelRowsCount + RowsCount, ColumnsCount + 1] = dt.Rows[RowsCount][ColumnsCount].ToString();
                                    }
oXL.Visible = false;
        oXL.UserControl = false;
         oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;
        oXL.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(FileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, "", "", false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
         oWB.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
         oXL.Workbooks.Close();
         oXL.Quit();
           int ExcelID;
                        GetWindowThreadProcessId(oXL.Hwnd, out ExcelID);
                        Process XLProcess = Process.GetProcessById(ExcelID);
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oSheet);
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWB);
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oXL);
                        XLProcess.Kill();
                        GC.Collect();
                        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                                } 

                }
```

Comment: Thanks, i will give this a try. :)

Comment: loop will be depend on the no of excel file genration